# Inner Margin on Highcharts Graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, highcharts

[image: Highcharts Graph Axis numbers overlap]

I want to keep the columns from overlapping the axis numbers.

- Key notes, I wanted the grid lines to go all the way to the left, filling the container.
- So I put a negative offset on the axis numbers and aligned them left.

I can't seem to find a way to force the columns to start farther in, adding an inner left margin.

Does anyone know a setting which could achieve this?

Comment: Can you share a JSFiddle of what you have? Makes it easier to solve your problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jhanifen/WMa55/5/

Comment: Made some small updates the the jsfiddle to make it easier to see.  Mainly adding the container so I can confirm the grid lines are going to the edges.

http://jsfiddle.net/jhanifen/WMa55/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the way you are defining your axis labels

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            borderWidth: 1,
            type: 'line',
            marginLeft: 2
        },
        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                align: 'left',
                x: 0,
                y: -2
            },
            title: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GqFzq/

Comment: Also i added a jsfiddle to the question, that is a more exact use case.

Comment: I have another idea. http://jsfiddle.net/jhanifen/WMa55/6/
Instead of moving the labels inside the chart, leave them out and extend the tick marks to the edge.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways:

- disabling categories and use [datetime](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type) type of xAxis, then you can set [minPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minPadding)
- using [offset](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.offset)